# How to use twitter API with date parameters?

Tags: api, python-2.7, search, twitter, tweets

We're building an app that analyzes twitter feed using streaming api. But it will only start analyzing after app starts. We need to download historical twitter data using API to initialize our system.

As per documentation twitter API only has until query parameter.

Is there a way to download /keep downloading the twits for given keyworkds with from to dates ?

We're using python.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation twitter API,  query method that you mentioned provides "since_id" parameter. If you want to keep downloading tweetsas they come then use  "until" parameter for first time n then "since _id" whenever you want to update

Comment: Does twitter put any limitation on what you can download ? I heard from my collegues that it only let you see 10% of tweets using API. Is it true ? I didn't find any concrete info in twitter docs. Is there a way to get over this liitation ?

Comment: Yes there's a limit to how many request you can make in a particular time interval (15 mins ) ..
read it in detail from "https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting"